# Syntax Error in while loop in Python

Tags: python-2.7

Please tell me whats wrong in the below coding? It gives the following error!

**SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character**

```
while True:
    for i in ["\","-","|","\\","|"]:
        print "%s\r" % i,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the first `\`:

```
while True:
    for i in ["\\","-","|","\\","|"]:
        # Here -^
        print "%s\r" % i,
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much!

Comment: while True:
    for i in ["/","-","|","\\","|"]:
        print "%s\r" % i,        When you type" /" with out" \" the program keeps on running how to stop it?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't escape the backslash and there's a comma at the end of the print line:

```
while True:
  for i in ["\\","-","|","\\","|"]:
    print "%s\r" % i
```